# PHP: file_get_contents fails during cron job, but only in 1 script. Can someone tell me why?

Tags: php, cron, file-get-contents

I've looked through the suggested answers and can't find what I'm looking for.

I have an internal web page providing statistics to senior management.

To reduce server load and web page load times,  I have a cron job  (cron_pateintcensus.php) that creates an XML file on the server.

This file is accessed by two scripts

ptc_xmlreader.php   //feeds the web page

ptc_emailer.php   //emails the report once a day

Everything worked fine on my test server, and I rolled this out to my production environment last night.

The email didn't go out when the cron job ran,  but it did when I went into my browser and called up the emailer script.

Here's the thing...

The script that reads the file for the web page and the one that writes the file have no problems accessing it.

The email script tells me it can't find the file...but I copied and pasted the file_get_contents  line from the script that works.

Both cron jobs run under the same user,  and that user has permissions on the folder and file.

I managed to get it working,  but I'm trying to figure out why it occurred and am hoping that someone can shed some light.

This is in PHP 5.4.36  run on a Turnkey Lamp Debian server.

This is the original code

`$output = file_get_contents('outputfiles/test.xml');`

Here's what I changed it to, to get it working

```
$rp = realpath(__DIR__.'/outputfiles');
$dc = file_get_contents($rp.'/test.xml');
```

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see by [What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38956):

> Add cd /home/xxxx/Documents/Scripts/ if you want your job to run in that directory. There's no reason why cron would change to that particular directory. **Cron runs your commands in your home directory.**

Since you aren't providing a full path you're running it from the home directory (you've probably cd'd to another location when running it manually).

This could mean the difference between

```
/home/foo/www/outputfiles/
```

and

```
/home/foo/outputfiles/ (does not exist)
```

This means when you use `__DIR__.'/outputfiles'` it works fine, as `__DIR__` resolves to the path that the *file* is in (and not the folder you're running the command from).

The solution is simple:

Provide a full path, either through `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` or use the [`chdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) method to change your working directory:

```
chdir(__DIR__);
// or
chdir('/home/foo/www/');
```